# Source nth commands from multiple folders

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to source total 80 files

```
source /home/*/foo
```

where

```
source /home/lee/foo
source /home/john/foo 
source /home/jane/foo
...
source /home/molly/foo
```

I want to source the first 20 before proceeding to the next 20 until I have sourced all 80 files.
Do not want to run all of them together at the same time.

I am using this, but not sure how to break them down

```
for file in /home/*/foo; do
   source */foo
done
```

Comment: The body of your `for` loop doesn't do what you think it does. It sources the first file in the expansion of the glob expression `*/foo` and the remaining filenames are supplied as positional parameters to that file. The file being sourced and passed parameters are the same on each iteration. Probably you meant `source "$file"`. And, what does this question have to do with python?

Comment: List your foo files into an array.  Then loop on the  array with a counter.  When your counter reaches 20, pause.  Then move on.  But @markp-fuso coimment is spot on, they are processed one after the other anyway.

Comment: See fix to the for loop below. Not clear what do you mean "first 20 before proceeding". The "source" is sequential, you will not proceed to #2, till #1 is done.

Comment: Please fix and undelete your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77487319/1745001 rather than just deleting it as it is an interesting problem that I expect many people come across and most solutions google returns will be buggy and fragile so it'd be good to have a robust solution available.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to loop to:

```
for file in /home/*/foo ; do
    source $file
done
```

It will source the 80 files in sequence, one at a time.